# How to root my Acer Tablet

Tags: tablet

I'd like to know if there a chance to root my Acer tablet 
to install ubuntu on it. There is method under Windows but this 
did not work on my tablet.

I've still seached the internet but can't find a solution.
Can some one help me?

Comment: Which Acer tablet? You say you tried something, but what exactly? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the procedure for installing Ubuntu touch including unlocking your device and backing it up prior to doing anything.

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

For supported devices (The only Acer device is Iconia A700);

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices